# Six questions in 24 hours: when does this reset?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Time reset/ending time for “Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 6 questions in a 24 hour period”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107726/time-reset-ending-time-for-sorry-you-are-only-allowed-to-ask-6-questions-in-a)

A couple of times I have been blocked from asking a question on SO because I have already asked 6 questions in the last 24 hours.

But I don't think this calculation is accurate.  There's no way I have asked six questions in the last 24 hours yet it is still giving me that message.

Does it wait a whole 24 hours before you can ask a question again?  If so, the message given is inappropriate.

Comment: @random I am pretty sure this has been asked before, but that is not the duplicate. The six questions in 24 hours limit **does not** reset at 00:00 UTC like the rest of the stuff.

Comment: Are you working from a shared IP?  [This block is IP based](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90474), so if you and your coworkers post a total of 6 or more questions in 24 hours, the above message will appear.

Comment: A related question (more related than the [What is an SE “day”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start) question, IMO) would be [Time reset/ending time for “Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 6 questions in a 24 hour period”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107726/time-reset-ending-time-for-sorry-you-are-only-allowed-to-ask-6-questions-in-a/107734#107734).   Edit: NullUserException's answer confirms that the problems are identical.   Closing as a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

> There's no way I have asked six questions in the last 24 hours yet it is still giving me that message.

Yes, there is a way:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291684/can-you-use-visual-c-sharp-2010-express-for-commercial-purposes
- [Why would a VB6 .frm file ever be full of binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291944/why-would-a-vb6-frm-file-ever-be-full-of-binary)
- [Is there any way to remove multiple forms from a VB6 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292923/is-there-any-way-to-remove-multiple-forms-from-a-vb6-project)
- [Can someone decompile my C# app and override the protection mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293520/can-someone-decompile-my-c-sharp-app-and-override-the-protection-mechanism)
- [Unable to open designer on form in C# 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294248/unable-to-open-designer-on-form-in-c-sharp-2010)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295893/start-a-new-c-sharp-project-in-winforms-or-wpf (deleted, 10k only)

And those are 6 questions that have been posted within the last 24 hours.

> Does it wait a whole 24 hours before you can ask a question again?

Unlike the other limits, which reset at 00:00 UTC, this one counts how many questions you've asked in the past 24 hours. At the time you tried to post a new question, there were 6 of them.

Right now, there should be 5, so you should be able to post another question by now.

Comment: Perhaps the restriction should be lifted for users posting in the [tag:VB6] tag, out of pity?

Comment: Incorrect, the first question in that list is more than 24 hours ago.

Comment: @CraigJ Try asking the question now, the restriction should've been lifted by now (but not at the time you posted your question).