# Is everybody limited to asking 6 question within a 24 hour period?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask)

Recently, I am learning iOS (iPad programming) and there are many new concepts and new frameworks, so I am asking questions more often than before.  (It can be no question in a whole month before).

But today I saw a message saying "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:  Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 6 questions in a 24 hour period".

Is it because I am asking all iOS questions?  What if I am asking Ruby, Javascript, and iOS question.  Is it still subject to this rule?

There is no such mentioning in the FAQ, so I wonder if this rule is true for everybody, or is it a flag by a moderator if he thinks a user is asking too many questions.

Does the 24 hour window mean Pacific Time or GMT -- so when it is a new day, we can immediately ask two questions, or do we have to wait till the 24-hour frame move away from one question first, and then we can ask one question.  And then we have to wait until the window move away from another question, and then we can ask one more?

Comment: I cannot pin you in my own question for I cannot get those characters. Please see Ben's comment on my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask), http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107726/time-reset-ending-time-for-sorry-you-are-only-allowed-to-ask-6-questions-in-a for the second part (24h is sliding window)

Comment: @Jae copy and paste won't work?  Or do those characters appear as boxes... I thought most browsers on most platforms nowadays show chinese characters (not in the case of Windows XP)

Comment: is it even by IP hit?  So I can go to the Apple store and ask questions on StackOverflow there?  (or use the iPhone to get on 3G to use a different IP, or use an ISP that gives different IP every time you disconnect)

Comment: Note that Jon Skeet can only ask one C# question. Thr moment he does that, the tag implodes since it loses faith in itself. Never again will there be a C# question.

Comment: @Manishearth [The facts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-sharp-or-net) [speak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) [against](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215548/whats-the-hardest-or-most-misunderstood-aspect-of-linq) [your](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256847/curious-null-coalescing-operator-custom-implicit-conversion-behaviour) [theory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/performance-surprise-with-as-and-nullable-types).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113954/158667, @動靜能量. A mod confirms that sliding window.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it because I am asking all iOS questions? What if I am asking Ruby,
>   Javascript, and iOS question. Is it still subject to this rule?

No. A user may ask:

- 50 questions over any 30-day period
- six questions over any 24-hour period
- one question over any 30-second period
- If you have less that 125 rep, you can only ask a question every 20 minutes

For your specific situation, see [Increase the limit of 6 questions in 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/increase-the-limit-of-6-questions-in-24-hours).

Comment: so it is a general rule...  how about the last part: is it "by a new day" or is it "a 24 hour moving frame"?

Comment: It's every UTC day.

Comment: @Ben Mat suggested it is sliding 24 hour window... is there an official rule?