# Is it possible to make a new account and use it to vote on the old account?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, sock-puppets

Is it possible for me to make a new account and get it 15 reputation and after that vote on my old account?

Comment: Sure. It's also possible the accounts will be merged or deleted.

Comment: Please don't downvote this, I don't remember it having been asked before and it's a perfectly cromulent question, if despicable. Now, if it's a dupe, let the downvoting begin.

Comment: For further searching: the magic word is "sock-puppet".

Comment: Tons of stuff has already been written on this subject.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76418/1288, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37331/1288, and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/

Comment: @jcolebrand I understand the reasoning for your request not to down vote. However, I think it is almost universal that this type of behavior is not permitted on web communities.

Comment: Yeah I know @Bill, but how many people like Ahmad here won't get that right away? I think it's best to leave it unclosed so that others can find this

Comment: @AndrewBarber see my comment just above this. It's all about the novices being able to find the information they want (assuming they search at all) and "sock-puppet" is not the same to most people as "new account vote"

Comment: @jcolebrand As I said, I understand your reasoning here. I just don't think it makes that big of a difference. Anyone who truly does not knoww what a "sock puppet" is and thinks to ask the question quite possibly isn't going to seacrh at all, in the first place.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Not knowing what a "sock puppet" is doesn't mean much. Side rant: I dislike the use of the term "sock puppet" anyway. It doesn't translate across cultural borders very well and carries no semantic meaning in itself unless you're already familiar with the term. If someone with poor command of English commits vote fraud, yelling at them about "sockpuppets" is pointless. I wish we'd just use "multiple accounts" or "alternate accounts" or something along those lines along with "vote fraud" (since having many accounts isn't illegal per se). */ahem* I digress, as per usual. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear My comment wasn't really about the specific term; it was about what ever we decide to call the behavior.

Comment: @jcolebrand I don't understand why this question should be treated any differently than any other duplicate.  We close questions for being duplicates with different wording all the time.  That's how they get linked together.

Comment: ok, how about don't close and delete it @BilltheLizard? For some reason I have it in my head that close-as-dupe means delete-in-30-days.

Comment: @jcolebrand If I find a closer match I'll close it but not delete it.  Questions closed as duplicates of others should definitely stick around as signposts.

Comment: @BilltheLizard TimStone and TheUnhandledException tell me it's migrated questions that delete after 30

Comment: It isn't migrated question!

Comment: -1 This is a _ridiculous_ question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

However, we monitor voting patterns and eventually will detect that you're committing vote fraud. Your accounts will then be merged and you will be suspended for a period of time that's pretty much at the moderators' discretion and depends on the severity of the fraud.

Comment: and if my new account rate everyone(not just me) can it be detected?

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Yes.

Comment: No problem and no detecting?

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee At this point it's like you walked into a police station and started asking them about their forensics procedures. You're not allowed to do it, so don't. The detectability isn't really important

Comment: How can I merge http://stackoverflow.com/users/1141438/2barnamenevis to http://stackoverflow.com/users/1003464/ahmadali-shafiee ?

Comment: @moguzalp: "team work" as in "vote rings"? Not cool either.

Comment: @moguzalp We have tools that can detect vote rings. We bust them pretty regularly.

Comment: @ahm, one example of what The Team is capable of: [Where has my account gone on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75288/where-has-my-account-gone-on-stack-overflow-is-it-deleted/75306#75306) ;-)

Comment: @ahmadali shafiee: I've merged them for you now.

Comment: @moguzalp I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to describe there.

Comment: @ahm, as for the votes that you will be missing tomorrow ([3 in 11 seconds, and 8 in 4 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1003464/ahmadali-shafiee?tab=reputation), that sounds too good to be true), see [Vote Fraud and You](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Since you're in the merge account mood anyway, would you mind merging my alt account http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/ into my main account http://stackoverflow.com/users/2915/ ?  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AdamDavis, this is the second time you've made this request. Per our two-strike policy, your main account will now be deleted. Thanks for playing.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee **WE SEE ALL**

Comment: @TheGhostofChristmasPast How says not ?!?

Comment: @moguzalp By the way, moderators don't see email sent to team@.

Comment: After the merge, what happens to the reputation gained from the vote fraud?

Comment: @ire_and_curses It's basically invalidated, since you can't vote for yourself. When accounts are merged, there's a rep recalc on the surviving account. Typically when we merge accounts that were involved in voting fraud, the surviving account's rep goes down as a result.

Comment: @casperOne: But the users of stackexchange are **too** many!!

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I was pondering over your comment about walking into a police station. Funny isn't it how we tend to Stereotype things? When OP asked the question, everyone intrinsically assumed he was wanting to find a loophole... where in all honesty, he could have been out trying to build a competitive site and wanting to know how the damn thing worked!! It's more like Somalian Police going into the Scotland Yard HQ and asking them how they solve a crime, no mater how pure their intents, they bloody hell will never get a straight answer!! :)