# Reputation removing service removed my friend's reputation but not mine

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

[I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1003464/ahmadali-shafiee) and [my friend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942659/mahdi?tab=answers) rate together. I asked [Is it possible to make a new account and use it to vote on the old account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118557/is-it-possible-to-make-a-new-account-and-use-it-to-vote-on-the-old-account) and you said our rating would be removed, but now just my fiend's reputation has been removed. What is happening?

Comment: Yes, his friend was me, and I know that the voting together for friendship is not good :( But now, his reputation not decreased, but mine was decreased.

Comment: Try manually triggering a reputation recalc at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation (button at the bottom)

Comment: Me or ahmadalli?

Comment: Both of you should do it.

Comment: @Mahdi ahmadall since that's the account that hasn't changed. But both of you can, although you can only do this once a day.

Comment: @ConradFrix:Done!!

Comment: Both of us did that. but nothing changed...

Comment: What is this doing?

Comment: @ConradFrix:thanks, It worked...

Comment: Just be thankful you still have your accounts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the devs ran a recalculation and your reputation went down to what it should be.
***Please don't make a habit of artificially inflating each other's reputation.***