# Sort questions by down vote

Tags: support, down-votes, sorting

When you are on Questions tab and click on "votes" tab you will see questions sorted by upvote. Is there any way to do other way round. I know no one want to see questions which are downvoted but there is no harm in looking at them(or stack overflow having a feature to view them in reverse order of voting) and try to understand why would questions be down voted.

Comment: They are not sorted by upvote. They are sorted by *score* (upvotes - downvotes). A question with 10 upvotes and 3 downvotes will be sorted below a question with only 8 upvotes (7 < 8).

Comment: I see. Didnt know that. Thanks.

Comment: I actually made a feature-request yesterday to [allow us to sort meta answers by upvote only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158223/158605), since voting can be different on meta and is often used to show agreement/disagreement instead of good/bad answer, so sometimes the best answers get hidden below answers which aren't as good simply due to users disagreeing with them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you sort by score (which is what "votes" actually means) and then go to the end of the list you'll see the posts with the most negative scores.

These do tend to be the most heavily down-voted posts though.

Comment: How do you sort by score instead of votes? I only have Active, Oldest, and Votes as my sorting options. Perhaps it's some moderator-only ability?

Comment: @Rachel - "votes" is actually "net votes" (i.e score). I was just picking up what was said in the comments. Edited post

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I was confused because Data.SE shows a field called Score for every post which is not the same as simply upvotes - downvotes :)

Comment: @Rachel - score should be the same as upvotes - downvotes. What makes you think it isn't? Don't forget data.se isn't live data.

Comment: Oops I think you're right. I'm probably mixing it up with the custom SE algorithm which determines whats a "hot" question, which I believe takes into account things like views, votes, the reputation of those who posted answers, etc